# Xen xm list showing Dom0 running less time than Guest Domain?

Tags: virtualization, xen

When I run xm list, it shows some thing like this:

Name       ID Mem(MiB) VCPUs State   Time(s)

Domain-0                                   0     4551     2 r-----   **1835.7**

windows2003server                                    1      1031     2 -b----   **4056.9**

Why the domU's running time can be bigger than Dom0's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the time field in the xm(1) command gives you the CPU time used by a given domain as accounted by Xen, not the elapsed time since the domain was started.

cheers!
n